# COM/OLE - the command or action openform isnt available now

Tags: ms-access, vba, autohotkey

The following error message was constantly appearing for me while trying to run the following OLE commands from AHK:

```
acc := ComObjActive("Access.Application")
acc.DoCmd.OpenForm("frmSearchLayer",0)  ;acc.DoCmd.OpenForm("frmSearchLayer",acNormal)
```

Answer (score 0):

When closing down my applications I noticed one of my VBA windows was currently open meanwhile being still connected to a COM object from the same database I had been trying to access.

The method to solve my user case:

Check task manager and quit all instances of MSACCESS.EXE